# Subdomain IP address changed but client still getting directed to old site

Tags: web, dns, subdomain, ip-address

I manage a web site that used to be hosted on Server A. I gave clients a subdomain url that pointed to this server, e.g. app1.example.com

I have moved my web site to a new server, Server B. I changed the IP address of app1.example.com (via the domain name host company) to point to the new server and this worked ok, for me at least. However, I have one client that is still getting directed to the old server.

When I get the client to ping app1.example.com it is trying to ping the old Server A. When I do a ping I get the correct Server B.

I am assuming that the reason for this is that the client must have the IP address cached somewhere. What do I need to tell the client? Would it be to run `ipconfig /fluchdns` or is the solution going to be more complicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time taken for the DNS records to update over the internet can be anything upto 48 hours.

How long ago did you make the switch to the new server?

If you need them to be able to access it immediatly ask them to edit there DNS record if it is possible. Else you will just need to wait for the DNS update to go through.

Comment: It was just a time issue. About an hour after posting this everything suddenly started working.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely not the client's fault. There are a lot of ISPs out there whose DNS server reloading intervals are quite long. It can take more than a day hours until a new name server entry is populated to all DNS servers. If it's very urgent, you could tell your client to add an entry to their `hosts` file.