# AWS, Recover from IP address change

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, web, ip-address

I want to recover from IP address change. My website used to be running fine, but after I allocated elastic IP address, it stopped working I want the website to be running again with new IP address. 
So my question is: **What steps must I consider and where should I look at first to recover from IP address change?**

I can't access that website with old DNS address or new DNS address. Is this DNS issue?

Notes that might be helpful:

- My web server seems to be using nginx, and I tried changing the configuration file with new dns, but that doesn't seem to do it.
- When I access new domain name, it redirects to old domain name.
  when I check with curl using `curl -I http://localhost:80`, it says `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as an add on. The problem is this configuration change in your nginx file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  my.old.domain.com;
    ...
}
```

Has to be changed to:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  my.new.domain.com;
    ...
}
```

So the DNS change can take up to 48 hours to propagate (it usually takes 10-30 minutes from experience, depending on your DNS provider)

When the DNS server wasn't propagated nginx would still redirect you to `my.old.domain.com`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think it was just time issue.

After changing web server configuration (nginx), I waited around 28 hours and it suddenly started working again.

Source:
[Subdomain IP address changed but client still getting directed to old site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339250/subdomain-ip-address-changed-but-client-still-getting-directed-to-old-site?rq=1)